# Square Webhook test is notication missing LocationId

Tags: square, square-connect

The Square Webhook test passes a body **without** a location_id

Does anyone know why?

{"entity_id":"xxxxxx-9b63-4f00-69e4-09833c3fda72","event_type":"TEST_NOTIFICATION","merchant_id":"xxxxTSXJSCRJ"}

Answer (score 0):

The webhook test is just supposed to help developers verify that their endpoint is working and that Square's servers can talk to it, it doesn't exactly emulate a notification that you would get from a merchant.